# Transform Scala code to Pyspark - Where clause

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the scala code as follows, I need to transform it to Pyspark, but beforehand I need to undrestand that what exactly where is doing here ?

```scala
val df= df1.join(df2,Seq("ID")).where('EVENT>='CONTINOUS_ENROL_START && 'EVENT <= 'CONTINOUS_ENROL_END)
```

Comment: `CONTINOUS_ENROL_START` and `CONTINOUS_ENROL_END` must be 2 variables containing relevant filters which are being used to create a where clause string -- which is passed in the `where()`

Comment: And from which data frame it is reading?

Comment: the result of the join will be used